# Randomising slides in Wordpress theme, JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am attempting to randomise my video background slides on a website theme running Wordpress.

I have done some reading and have figured out I may have to create an array using JavaScript.

The site currently shows 3 slides on the home page and an arrow can be clicked to change slides.

I am very happy to do some research and attempt this myself though don't know where to start as the scripts I've found online and tutorials aren't helping me.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

I am a graphic designer so have minimal coding experience.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a little bit of Math skills and a little bit of javascript and you're almost there ;)

Have a look at `Math.random()` then you use that to retrieve the values you need in your array...

best of luck!

---

reference: [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)